# What are the advantages of HAproxy over AWS ELB?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Under what scenarios, we can opt for HAproxy load balancing solution over AWS elastic load balancing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally you can look at deploying HAProxy when you need a more configurable LB layer.

ELB is the most cost effective solution that you will probably find on AWS, but it has issues handling large spikes of traffic (50% every 5 minutes, according to this article: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479). Also it doesn't play well with long connections, as any idle connection for more than 60 seconds is automatically dropped.

Another good use-case for HAProxy instead of ELB is when you want to do manipulate traffic based on incoming URLs or cookies.

If all you're looking for is a dead-simple LB solution that you can manage without hassles go for ELB. If control is what you're after, go for HAProxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use [AWS Local Zones](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/localzones/?nc=sn&loc=0), HAProxy (or other non-AWS load balancing platform) could be the only option as ELB is not supported in all Local Zones.

If you're going to use local zones where ELB is not supported, you can argue that you start using HAProxy for all your load balancing needs to simplify your architecture to only one load balancer platform and learn that one really well. But there are pros and cons to this tactic of course.